# Excel / PowerPivot / time series average

Tags: pivot-table, excel-2013, powerpivot

I'm stuck on an Excel PowerPivot related problem that I can't seem to get a grip on:

I'm trying to measure the volume of customers at each hour and depending on which day of the week

I have a table that records the (1) date a customer visited, (2) the day of the week (Mon-Sun), (3) what hour of the day they arrived, and (4) the customer type (A,B,C etc).

Below is an example of the log and what I am trying to achieve in the pivot table:

[Exhibit A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaKYg.png)

So, if two customers came the first week, and one the second week, then the measure should report 1.5 [1.5 = average(1,2)]

I am just positively stumped. I hope I've been able to explain it well enough.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put Day of Week and Time of Day in the Pivot table columns, and the Customer Type on the rows.

Your measures are as simple as

```
Customers:=
COUNTROWS( 'MyTable' )

Average:=
[Customers] / DISTINCTCOUNT( 'MyTable'[Date] )

Min:=
MINX(
    VALUES( 'MyTable'[Date] )
    ,[Customers]
)
```

Max is the same as Min, but with MAXX()